# Having some trouble with this method

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble making this method, I thought I was doing it right but obviously I'm not, I'm working on my changeLight() method, but I'm getting a redline on my if statement, and I'm not sure why. The method should look at the currentState and change it, if the currentState is State.GO then it should change to State.WARN, if the currentState is State.Warn then it should change to State.STOP, if the current state is State.STOP then it should change to State.GO.  It's just a simple stoplight program.

Need a little help here, any is appreciated, thanks.

Here's my code.

```
package trafficlight;

import java.awt.Color;

public class TrafficLight {
  private int goDuration;
  private int stopDuration;
  private int warnDuration;
  public enum State {STOP, GO, WARN};
  public Color GO_COLOR = Color.green;
  public Color STOP_COLOR = Color.red;
  public Color OFF_COLOR = Color.darkGray;
  public Color WARNING_COLOR = Color.yellow;
  private State currentState;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  public TrafficLight(int goDuration, int stopDuration, int warnDuration) {
    this.goDuration = goDuration = 2;
    this.stopDuration = stopDuration = 2;
    this.warnDuration = warnDuration = 1;
    this.currentState = currentState = State.GO;
  }

  public static void changeLight() {
    if (currentState = State.GO) {
      currentState = State.WARN;
    }
  }

  public int getGoDuration() {
    return goDuration;
  }

  public void setGoDuration(int goDuration) {
    this.goDuration = goDuration;
  }

  public int getStopDuration() {
    return stopDuration;
  }

  public void setStopDuration(int stopDuration) {
    this.stopDuration = stopDuration;
  }

  public int getWarnDuration() {
    return warnDuration;
  }

  public void setWarnDuration(int warnDuration) {
    this.warnDuration = warnDuration;
  }

  public State getCurrentState() {
    return currentState;
  }

  public void setCurrentState(State currentState) {
    this.currentState = currentState;
  }
}
```

Comment: the  comparison operator is == and not =

Answer (score 1):

You're using `=` in your if statement.  That's the assignment operator.  You want to use `==` which is the equality operator.

The reason you get the "red line" is because you said `currentState` should become `State.GO` when you meant to ask, "is `currentState` equal to `State.GO`?"

---

That's just one of many errors.  Another error is this:

```
public static void changeLight();
```

You shouldn't have a semicolon there.  You want to wrap the code that follows in curly braces to say, "This is the code of my method".

---

When you fix that you should have:

```
public static void changeLight() {
    if(currentState == State.GO){
        currentState = State.WARN;


    }
}
```

But that will be an error because this method is static and `currentState` is not a static variable.  You can fix that by changing the signature to:

```
    public void changeLight()
```

Comment: It is, illegal start of type, cannot find symbol class currentState and cannot find symbol class GO

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I eddited my constructor, does that look okay?

Comment: No, that's unusual.  What do you *think* you're doing there?

Comment: Well I want my constructor to set the variables to their starting values, so currentState = State.GO, goDuration = 2, stopDuration = 2, warnDuration = 1.

Comment: Then why do you *also* want people to pass in `int goDuration` to set it to different values?  You can't have it both ways simultaneously.

Comment: Could I just take out this.goDuration?

Answer (score 0):

check your syntax.

```
public static void changeLight(){
  if(currentState == State.GO){
      currentState = State.WARN;
  }
}
```

edit: and of course == instead of =

Answer (score 0):

```
if(currentState == State.go){
    currentState = State.WARN;
}
```

= is assignment but == is the equivalence test. What you were doing is saying currentState is now equal to State.go (currentState = State.go) what you want is *is currentState equal to State.go* (currentState == State.go)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using your enum as a [Finite State machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) like this

```
 public enum State {
   STOP, GO, WARN;
   public Color getColor() {
    switch (this) {
    case GO: // Green 
      return Color.green;
    case WARN:
      return Color.yellow;
    }
    // I don't think you want a State for OFF.
    return Color.red; // Red
  }

   State nextLight() {
    switch (this) {
    case GO: // Green -> Yellow
      return WARN;
    case STOP: // Red -> Green
      return GO;
    }
    return STOP; // Default to Red (Yellow -> Red)
  }

 // The enum is now a FSM.
 public void changeLight(){
   currentState = currentState.nextLight();
 }
```